# Can Anthill Beanshell script make a HTTP connection?

Tags: http, beanshell, anthill

I use [Anthill Pro](http://www.anthillpro.com/) for build and deployment management. I'm attempting to configure Anthill to make a HTTP POST or GET to a web server after a deployment has completed. I'm passing basic information regarding the deployment to a web application.

It looks like writing a Beanshell script is the way to do this in Anthill (I'm open to suggestions), but the [documentation](http://www.beanshell.org/) does not seem to offer an obvious way to do this.

Can a Beanshell script from Anthill make a HTTP connection to accomplish this, or is there a better way?

Example of the connection I'm trying to make:

```
http://myServer/myScript/?param1=deployValue1&param2=deployValue2
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Are you just trying to hit a URL and validate that some text on it is there? If so we have a plugin baking that does this sort of thing. Shoot me a mail at eric@urbancode.com (or file a support ticket) and we can get that over to you.